# How can I manipulate/create a Google Document via API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Spreadsheets have their own API to add rows, modify cells, etc. How can I create a Google Document via an API to add text, bold, tables, etc. like a Word document?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

In their list of apps API, documents are not even mentioned:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/app-apis

Even the Drive API doesn't mention creating/formatting a word processing document specifically:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

There is the Google Docs API, but it's deprecated and doesn't mention formatting a Doc, only converting an existing Microsoft or text document:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

Comment: You need a data api: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#what_can_this_api_do

Comment: @voscausa Does Google have one for Docs like Spreadsheets? I'm leaning towards creating a PDF in memory and uploading to Drive.

Comment: No. But for generating PDF's have a look at this article: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Generating-PDFs-on-App-Engine-Python-and-introducing-Mapvelopes

Comment: @voscausa Thanks, but I need something for Java.

Comment: Google recently launched an API for Google Docs https://developers.google.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

It has an api but its only available from apps script. Look at DocumentApp.
You can then publish a service that does the work.